# How to use Dynamic Type in TextView inside Table View Cell

Tags: ios, swift, accessibility, dynamic-type-feature

I want to implement Dynamic Type in my application, so the app can adapt to user font preference. I have a Table View with 3 static cells. The first and second one has `UITextField` and they work fine without any problems. The third one which is a cell with `UITextView` doesn't scale. Dynamic Type is set to on and the font is Body.

Here's my code in my `UITableViewController`.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100 
    setupTextFieldsAndTextView()
}

func setupTextFieldsAndTextView() {
    emailTF.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.asciiCapable
    titleTF.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.asciiCapable
    messageTextView.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.asciiCapable

    emailTF.returnKeyType = .next
    titleTF.returnKeyType = .next
    messageTextView.returnKeyType = .default

    emailTF.delegate = self
    titleTF.delegate = self
    messageTextView.delegate = self
}
```

and `UITableView` delegate

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableView.automaticDimension
}
```

I want to have the same design as in the iOS calendar app. Cell scale based on chosen font type but `UITextView` is still scrollable and the text inside is also chosen by the user. `UITextView` in the screen is a cell with text placeholder "Notes".
[image: ios calendar 1]

[image: ios calendar 2]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43398867/dynamic-cell-height-for-textview-swift

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37014919/expand-uitextview-and-uitableview-when-uitextviews-text-extends-beyond-1-line

Comment: @ShadeToD : when you claim that the cell with UITextView doesn't scale with Dynamic Type, are you talking about the height or the font size ?

Comment: @XLE_22 i mean height of the cell and font of the text inside that cell. Check out 2 photos from iOS calendar app. It scale cell height and also text inside cell. ( cell with placeholder "Notes")

Comment: You can try your textview cell listen to `UIContentSizeCategory.didChangeNotification` and then refresh your textview?

Answer (score 0):

Few steps to be checked for the `UITextView` :

- It must be inside your cell.
- Its constraints must be set up with the cell.
- Its text style **MUST** be selected if you want to use the Dynamic Type feature.
- Its `Automatically Adjusts Font` property **MUST** be ticked in the Interface Builder if you want to use the Dynamic Type feature.
- Turn off the `Scrolling Enabled` property in the Scroll View section of the Attributes Inspector.

Once all these elements are checked, **the cell height and the `UITextView` font size should adapt the desired size**.

I suggest you take a look at this [detailed summary](http://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios-wwdc-17245.html#TableViewCells) of the WWDC 2017 video that perfectly explains how to build an app with Dynamic Type.

Comment: its better if you answer along with screenshots

Comment: @ArshadShaik: the detailed summary I suggest contains many useful information and an efficient example that expose code and techniques that screenshots couldn't replace at all in my view. 

Answer (score 0):

Please check this for a dynamic height of textView in tableView.

```
// Tableview Delegate Method
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "NotesCell", for: indexPath) as! NotesCell

    cell.txtViewNotes.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.txtViewNotes.delegate = self

    return cell;
}

// Textview Delegate Method
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        adjustFrames(textView)
}

// Custom Method    
func adjustFrames(_ textView: UITextView)  {
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: textView.tag, section: 0)
    let cell = yourTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! NotesCell

    UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false);

    self.yourTableView.beginUpdates()
        cell.constNoteHeight.constant = textView.contentSize.height
        textView.beginFloatingCursor(at: CGPoint.zero)
        textView.endFloatingCursor()
    self.yourTableView.endUpdates()

    UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true);

}
```

> Notes: **constNoteHeight** is the height constant of textView.

Answer (score -1):

Use [GrowingTextView](https://github.com/KennethTsang/GrowingTextView), For UITextView

Comment: I want to have the same design like in iOS calendar app. Inside that app textview which is inside cell doesn't grow when u type text.

Comment: Hello @ShadeToD, i faced same issue so i m using GrowingTextview inside cell.
Please check my screen: http://prntscr.com/ndjahg